# Successful heroku run rake db:migrate but columns don't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, rake, migrate

I added a new column called level to my table called ClassRequest, ran a rake db:migrate on localhost and the view worked perfectly. Pushed the changes to heroku and the view met an error "NoMethodError: undefined method `level' for #"

So I ran heroku run rake db:migrate and that appears to be successful, showing the codes below.

```
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
==  AddDetailsToClassRequests: migrating ======================================
-- add_column(:class_requests, :level, :string)
   -> 0.0684s
==  AddDetailsToClassRequests: migrated (0.0713s) =============================
```

But when I load the associated view, I still have this error "NoMethodError: undefined method `level' for #".

I'm new to rails so I don't know what's wrong, nor how do I know how to check what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
heroku restart
```

Check the heroku's docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

> After running a migration you’ll want to restart your app with heroku
>   restart to reload the schema and pickup any schema changes.

Comment: Just saved me some hair pulling :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to restart you app after you've run the migration. Try

`heroku restart`

and see if things improve.